# Magento 1.x ssl certificate issue

Tags: magento-1.7, ssl, https

I've installed the magento setup and created an ssl certificate for https requests(i am working in localhost on Ubuntu), but when I create an account in my websites it shows firstly "the connection cannot be trusted" and after changing https to http it says "not found" 
My other routes are working properly excepts for the ones which goes through https. I know its a certificate issue, so I want to remove the ssl certificate and reinstall it, but I can't figure which files to remove in order to remove the ssl certificate. Can any one help me out